# Grafana with SSL and Apache reverse proxy continuously redirects

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, redirect, apache2, grafana

I am attempting to move my Grafana install from a non-SSL to SSL link. It sits behind an Apache reverse proxy and worked fine before I tried to set up SSL.

I have seen many tutorials that look like [this one](https://statusengine.org/tutorials/Grafana-Bionic/), which is what I have done.

My Apache config looks like this (with the domain name changed to `example.com`)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin nermel@example.com
    ServerName grafana.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/grafana.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/grafana.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName grafana.example.com
    ServerSignature Off

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /opt/repos/dehydrated/certs/grafana.example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/repos/dehydrated/certs/grafana.example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /opt/repos/dehydrated/certs/grafana.example.com/chain.pem
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/grafana.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/grafana.example.com-access_log common

 </VirtualHost>
```

In my `grafana.ini` I've only changed the following. Everything else is still commented out and using defaults:

```
domain = grafana.example.com
root_url = https://grafana.example.com
```

I have no errors in my grafana.log file and it starts up as expected. It ends with

```
t=2019-05-30T14:51:31-0500 lvl=info msg="HTTP Server Listen" logger=http.server address=0.0.0.0:3000 protocol=http subUrl= socket=
```

My DNS entries and SSL certificates are correctly installed.

If I visit the full URL (`grafana.example.com`) Apache performs a ton of redirects and then the request fails with Chrome reporting that to many redirects have occurred. My access log looks like this (with the IPs scrubbed)

```
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:57 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 581
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:57 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 581
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 581
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 581
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:58 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:59 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:59 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:59 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:59 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:59 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
162.158.xxx.xxx - - [30/May/2019:14:51:59 -0500] "GET /?orgId=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 580
```

There are no errors in my apache error log.

Prior to trying to move to SSL, my virtual host looked like this and worked as expected:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin nermel@example.com
    ServerName grafana.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/


    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/grafana.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/grafana.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

My `apache2ctl -S` output is as follows (again, with the domain scrubbed). My other SSL virtualhost is pointing to a GitLab instance and is working without issues:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server default (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost default (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost repos.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf:18)
         port 80 namevhost grafana.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/grafana.conf:1)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server repos.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf:27)
         port 443 namevhost repos.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf:27)
         port 443 namevhost grafana.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/grafana.conf:13)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

What do I need to do so that I can use Apache as a reverse proxy and use SSL to connect to Grafana?

Comment: Do you have `NameVirtualHost *:443` directive before all your SSL virtual hosts, including default? Also could you please add to question config from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/gitlab.conf`